# how to press alt + num x (any numpad keys) using pyautogui

Tags: python

i'm trying to print some symbols using python. i can print it with keyboard by clicking alt+numx (x=number of the symbol).
i'm trying to do this using pyautogui but it is not working.

````
             *import pyautogui*
             pyautogui.keyDown('alt')
             pyautogui.press('num 1')
             pyautogui.keyUp('alt') ```



if there other library to do this help me.
**this following text is not related to the question so do not read it.**
Edit: following is the official solution from Google (link)

Summary
Google Maps SDK thread crashes App (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) - Solution Offered

Description
On April 23 2020 starting at 11:30 PDT, Google served for 4 hours an update to the configuration of a Maps mobile component, triggering crashes in Maps SDKs for Android and iOS. Applications on devices that downloaded this version of the configuration (during the outage period) were vulnerable to the crash. Workaround solutions are offered for Maps SDKs for Android and iOS.

Maps SDK for Android
````

Answer (score 0):

Hi Refer to the document it briefly  mentioned.

https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html

Try below if work for you

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'num 1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea (if you need one character only) is to copy it and do:

```
with pyautogui.hold('ctrl'):
    pyautogui.press(['v'])
```